How to run steps in parallel in Buildbot
In Buildbot, is there a way run steps within a builder in parallel? I couldn't find any documentation on that.
For example, I want these 2 steps to be executed in parallel.
factory.addStep(Parallel(
    steps=[
        ShellCommand(
            name='test.1',
            command=["run", "test1"]
        ),
        ShellCommand(
            name='test.2',
            command=["run", "test2"]
        )
    ]
))

I couldn't find parallel implementation in steps.py
